# Accessing oracle database tables from ms access using pass through query

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, ms-access

I am trying to access oracle database tables from ms access.
initially it was taking a lot of time(related to performance issues)

Now I have a stored procedure in oracle and i am trying to call it from ms access.
But i need to pass some parameters to the stored procedure from ms access.
Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: Take a lock at this http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/passthrough3.php

Answer (score 1):

In Access 2007 or 2010, click on the "Design" tab at the top of the page.  In the "Query Type" section, select "Pass-Through".  You'll then be presented with a notepad view where you can type in your PLSQL code.